# Load textarea attribute in product page via custom block

Tags: product-attribute, custom-block

I'm trying to show an attribute in product page.
I have create my .phtml file with the bellow code.

```
<?php       
  $_prodID = Mage::registry('current_product')->getId();
  $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_prodID);
?>

<?php echo $_product->getData('assembly_instructions'); ?>
```

and I'm calling the block with this code

```
{{block type="core/template" template="catalog/product/view/attributes/assembly.phtml"}}
```

The above code loads the info of the attribute but it show's the same info in every product.

Doesn't load different info of each product, loads the info that i will see for the first time and this will be cached.

I have search it here in forum and i have follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13883139/how-to-add-product-attribute-on-product-page-via-cms-block-magento but hasn't help a lot.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: I solved similar task few months ago. I need only to remember what I did. Do you mean catalog_product_list page or catalog_product_view ?

Comment: i think i want the product view. 
The product page with the product details

Answer (score 0):

Initially I'd recommend do not reinitialize product again. It cause additional time. On product view page product is already initialized and can be reached from `Mage::registry('current_product')`

You need to verify setting inside attribute edit page:

[image]

Set yes for this field. Not sure, you may probably will need to reindex catalog. And then this attribute will be accessible on catalog/product/view page.

```
$product = Mage::registry('current_product');
echo $product->getYourAttributeName();
```

**Upd.1**

Okay. To hide from additional information I can offer next:

```
/**
 * $excludeAttr is optional array of attribute codes to
 * exclude them from additional data array
 *
 * @param array $excludeAttr
 * @return array
 */
public function getAdditionalData(array $excludeAttr = array())
```

as you can see there is param $excludeAttr. You just need to transfer your attribute inside this method in template...

> /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml

```
<?php if($_additional = $this->getAdditionalData(array('your_attribute_code'))): ?>
```

Comment: Sorry if i didn't understand well, but if i set the option "Visible on Product View page on Front end" then the information it should appear on additional information tab and i don't want that.

I want to appear this on custom position

Comment: I've updated my post.

Comment: Thanks for everything but the client changes his mind and he wants the attribute inside the additional information.

So the solution was simple thanks again.

Comment: Ok, glad to hear that everything is ok. Good luck